# Using PostgreSQL parameters with booleans in EXECUTE / USING

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, plpgsql

i want to use parameters for my dynamic queries. I have a statements like so:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM boards AS b WHERE b.slug = $1 AND $2'
USING filter_slug, parent_id_query;
```

I get a `ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text`

if i do it like this:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM boards AS b WHERE b.slug = ''' || filter_slug || ''' AND ' || parent_id_query;
```

it works though.

I feel like i am missing something / not understanding something. Please help.

Comment: "x and y" means both x and y must render to some form of boolean expression -- they need to yield either a true or a false.  b.slug = $1 is definitely either true or false, but $2 would only do this if it were a boolean.  I get the idea `parent_id_query` is not a boolean...  is it a query?  If so, you can only pass values to parameters.  Parameters don't just do string substitutions.

Comment: Ah okay. That was helpful. I think i could fix it by only replacing the `filter_slug` with a parameter and leaving `parent_id_query` as it was. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is how parameters are used.  Parameters are not macros that replace arbitrary text inside a SQL statement.  Instead, they are literal values assigned to "variables" inside the code.  These values are typically numbers, strings, or dates.

In particular, parameters cannot be used for:

- identifiers (columns names and table names)
- function names
- operators
- SQL keywords
- general expressions

So, unfortunately, you have to construct that part of the query without a generic parameter (although you can have `$2 = $3`)

Comment: Or, to put it shorter, you can use a parameter almost anywhere in a `SELECT`, INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement where you could use a constant (literal).